# Google Maps v3 custom marker icon is in center and does not keep its position on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement **FontAwesome** icons as a marker on Google Maps. So far I made it work, but at the moment icons are in the middle of the screen, at they stay there no matter what (they refuse to be on the dedicated positions).

Example of the code at this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk72x9ue/)

JS code:

```
function FontAwesomeMarker(latlng, map, args) {
  this.latlng = latlng;
  this.args = args;
  this.setMap(map);
}

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
  var self = this,
    panes = this.getPanes(),
    marker = this.marker;

  if (!marker) {
    marker = this.marker = document.createElement('div');
    marker.className = 'marker';

    var icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.className = 'fa fa-' + this.args.icon;
    icon.style.fontSize = this.args.fontSize;
    icon.style.color = this.args.color;
    icon.anchorPoint = new google.maps.Point(0, 49)
    marker.appendChild(icon);

    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);
    if (point) {
      marker.style.left = (point.x - 25) + 'px';
      marker.style.top = (point.y - 25) + 'px';
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
      alert('You clicked on a custom marker!');
      google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
    });

    panes.overlayImage.appendChild(marker);
  }
};

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.marker) {
    this.marker.parentNode.removeChild(this.marker);
    this.marker = null;
  }
};

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
  return this.latlng;
};

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
    mapOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var markers = [{
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
      icon: 'cutlery',
      color: '#346698',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8939, 151.207333),
      icon: 'anchor',
      color: '#B90C13',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.895, 151.195),
      icon: 'automobile',
      color: '#39A00F',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.905, 151.195),
      icon: 'headphones',
      color: '#000',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9039, 151.207333),
      icon: 'child',
      color: '#26C2C3',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
  ]

  markers.forEach(function(item) {
    new FontAwesomeMarker(
      item.latLan,
      map, {
        icon: item.icon,
        color: item.color,
        fontSize: item.fontSize
      }
    );
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `marker.style.position = 'absolute';`

```
if (!marker) {
  marker = this.marker = document.createElement('div');
  marker.className = 'marker';
  marker.style.position = 'absolute';
  // <snip>
```

To get the markers to drag with the map, you also need to break the `draw` method apart, put some of it into an `onAdd` method (see the related question):

```
FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
      marker = this.marker = document.createElement('div');
      marker.className = 'marker';
    marker.style.position = 'absolute';

      var icon = document.createElement('i');
      icon.className = 'fa fa-' + this.args.icon;
      icon.style.fontSize = this.args.fontSize;
      icon.style.color = this.args.color;
    icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(0, 49)
      marker.appendChild(icon);
    var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(marker);
}

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
    var self = this,
    marker = this.marker;

    var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);
        if (point) {
          marker.style.left = (point.x - 25) + 'px';
          marker.style.top = (point.y - 25) + 'px';
        }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
        alert('You clicked on a custom marker!');           
        google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
      });

};
```

from this related question on HTMLMarker: [Adding Custom Markers (HTMLMarkers) to Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434206/adding-custom-markers-htmlmarkers-to-clustering)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j62swmcf/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

```js
function FontAwesomeMarker(latlng, map, args) {
  this.latlng = latlng;
  this.args = args;
  this.setMap(map);
}

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  marker = this.marker = document.createElement('div');
  marker.className = 'marker';
  marker.style.position = 'absolute';

  var icon = document.createElement('i');
  icon.className = 'fa fa-' + this.args.icon;
  icon.style.fontSize = this.args.fontSize;
  icon.style.color = this.args.color;
  icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(0, 49)
  marker.appendChild(icon);
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayImage.appendChild(marker);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, "click", function(event) {
    alert('You clicked on a custom marker!');
    google.maps.event.trigger(self, "click");
  });
}
FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
  var self = this,
    marker = this.marker;

  var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);
  if (point) {
    marker.style.left = (point.x - 25) + 'px';
    marker.style.top = (point.y - 25) + 'px';
  }
};

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.remove = function() {
  if (this.marker) {
    this.marker.parentNode.removeChild(this.marker);
    this.marker = null;
  }
};

FontAwesomeMarker.prototype.getPosition = function() {
  return this.latlng;
};

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
    mapOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: myLatlng,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var markers = [{
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
      icon: 'cutlery',
      color: '#346698',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8939, 151.207333),
      icon: 'anchor',
      color: '#B90C13',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.895, 151.195),
      icon: 'automobile',
      color: '#39A00F',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.905, 151.195),
      icon: 'headphones',
      color: '#000',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
    {
      latLan: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9039, 151.207333),
      icon: 'child',
      color: '#26C2C3',
      fontSize: '35px'
    },
  ]

  markers.forEach(function(item) {
    new FontAwesomeMarker(
      item.latLan,
      map, {
        icon: item.icon,
        color: item.color,
        fontSize: item.fontSize
      }
    );
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed. `remove` should be `onRemove` also according to the docs.

Comment: That is also addressed in the related question referenced in my answer.  Would probably only be needed if they are being removed from the map.

Comment: The `remove` seems to work as is: https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j62swmcf/3/