# Adding Multiple HTML Markers to Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-maps

I've been trying to add multiple HTML markers on Google Maps so I can add CSS styles and also include text inside it and also animate the markers as you zoom in and out so I can make them smaller or bigger or turn them into a dot depending on the zoom level or add icons.

The style that I am trying to achieve is shown in this following example.

[image: Map Markers]

I've tried my best but the best I could muster up without critical errors is this following, for some reason they are stacking in one marker:

[image]

Here is the code I got.

```js
function init() {

  // LEFT
  var locations = [
    ['500k', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
    ['1.3M', -33.923036, 151.259052, 2],
    ['2.3M', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['750k', -33.800101, 151.287478, 4],
    ['200K', -33.950198, 151.259302, 5],
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var price = locations[i][0];
    var latMarker = locations[i][1];
    var lngMarker = locations[i][2];

    function HTMLMarker(lat, lng) {
      this.lat = lat;
      this.lng = lng;
      this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {}

    //init your html element here
    HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
      div = document.createElement('div');
      div.className = "arrow_box d-flex";
      div.innerHTML = "<div class='m-auto'>SR " + price + "</div>";
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);
    }

    HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
      var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.style.left = position.x + 'px';
      panes.overlayImage.style.top = position.y - 30 + 'px';
    }

    // to use it
    var htmlmarker = new HTMLMarker(latMarker, lngMarker);

    htmlmarker.setMap(map);

  }

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mapdiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#mapdiv2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.arrow_box {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px -30px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.arrow_box img {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  top: 30px;
  left: 0px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Map Test</title>
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body class="bg-dark d-flex p-1" onload="init()">

  <div class="border border-primary bg-dark rounded" id="mapdiv">
  </div>

</body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>


<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

</html>
```

Comment: related question: [Adding Custom Markers (HTMLMarkers) to Clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434206/adding-custom-markers-htmlmarkers-to-clustering)

Comment: It is still in beta but you can try [Advanced Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/overview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

- There is no need to declare the HTMLMarker functions within the for loop. Declare it outside and call the `new HTMLMarker(...)` and `setMap()` function within the loop.
- I have added the price in the create function so you can refer to it as `this.price` and use it that way in the `onAdd` function.
- The same goes for the `div` you are creating. Use `this.div = document.createElement('div');` so you can refer to it in other functions.
- I have used `overlayMouseTarget` which seems more appropriate than `overlayImage` for holding HTML markers.
- In the `draw()` function, set the position of `this.div` instead of setting the position of the entire map pane.
- Last but not least, your `.arrow_box` elements need to be `position: absolute;`

A few more things:

- Include `<script>` tags within the `<body>` element
- Declare your map initialization function `init()` as a callback in the api call `&callback=init` and use `defer` attribute to make sure the callback executes after the full DOM was parsed by the browser
- Declare the `init()` function as a property of the `window` object
- I fixed your CSS, the arrows can't display if you have `overflow: hidden;` on the box and you need correct `top` and `left` values
- Given your box design, you need to offset the top value by 35px `this.div.style.top = (position.y - 35)` in the `draw()` function if you want the tip of the arrow to be on the exact coordinates
- Have a look at [Advanced Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advanced-markers/overview) but it is still in Preview (pre-GA)

```js
function init() {

  var locations = [
    ['500k', -33.890542, 151.274856, 1],
    ['1.3M', -33.923036, 151.259052, 2],
    ['2.3M', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['750k', -33.800101, 151.287478, 4],
    ['200K', -33.950198, 151.259302, 5],
  ];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  });

  function HTMLMarker(lat, lng, price) {
    this.price = price;
    this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  HTMLMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {}
  HTMLMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    this.div = document.createElement('div');
    this.div.className = "arrow_box d-flex";
    this.div.innerHTML = "<div class='m-auto'>SR " + this.price + "</div>";
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.div);
  }

  HTMLMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
    this.div.style.left = position.x + 'px';
    this.div.style.top = (position.y - 35) + 'px';
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    let htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(locations[i][1], locations[i][2], locations[i][0]);
    htmlMarker.setMap(map);
  }

}

window.init = init;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mapdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.arrow_box {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px -30px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow_box img {
  min-width: 150px;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-top-color: blue;
  border-width: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="mapdiv"></div>

<!-- 
  The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
  document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
  and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
  with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
  -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=init" defer></script>
```

Comment: I see my mistake, thanks.

Also I really like those Advanced Markers